# Updating application data structures after deserializing XML file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

What is the simplest way to update an ObservableCollection based data structure after deserializing an XML file?

1. Clear the current data structure and add the elements from the XML deserializing, thus keeping the DataContext bindings.
2. Create a new data structure, and set the DataContext to the new structure.

Setting the Window DataContext to `null` and then back to its ViewModel worked.  But then the DataContext has to be reset on every Window and UserControl, which seems like somewhat of a dirty hack.

**EDIT:**

Based on [mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252182/mm8)'s answer, I found this Enhanced ObservableCollection implementation:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249311/Enhanced-ObservableCollection

Since I just needed an implementation of ObservableCollection that can suppress change notifications, I found that ReactiveList had too much overhead for my needs.

Comment: How about clearing and re-populating the same ObservableCollection?

Comment: That's what I meant with the first option (see improved question formatting).  But which one is better?

Comment: The problem is that the data structure is instantiated be fore the View is, which in some cases binds to the first element in some of the ObservableCollections.  So when clearing the ObservableCollection, I will create a situation where the View binds to an element that isn't there, before the ObservableCollection is populated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clear and re-populate the same `ObservableCollection<T>`. But you may want to use an implementation of the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface that supports suppressing the change notifications, such as ReactiveUI's `ReactiveList<T>`: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/b551dfe13c21090b7529bd69539433bbe91b63fb/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveList.cs.

You can then update the data-bound collection like this:

```
ReactiveList<object> sourceCollection = new ReactiveList<object>();
...
using (sourceCollection.SuppressChangeNotifications())
{
    sourceCollection.Clear();
    foreach(var item in ...)
        sourceCollection.Add(item);
}
```

...which will only raise a single `CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: Ah, great answer!  It also answered another question I had, regarding firing off notifications left and right when repopulating the existing data structure. :-)